# Empty folders without changing folder's Last Modified Date

Tags: directory, file-metadata

I wish to delete the contents of around 600 folders on my Linux Mint PC but I want to retain the Last Modified Date of the top-most folder as it existed before deleting the files. This would be equivalent to noting the Last Modified Date of the folder, deleting the contents of the folder and then using the touch command to restore the folder date back to what it was before deleting its contents.

Can this be done as a single CLI command, and if so, how please?

I haven't tried anything to achieve this as I have no idea where to start.

Thanks

Comment: Note there are three dates (or four in some file systems) held for each directory. The Access and Modify dates can be reset (either, or both together) by `touch`. The Change date (showing when the directory last had entries added or deleted), and the Birth date (showing when the inode for the file was last assigned) cannot be changed by `touch`.

Answer (score 0):

This works. Thanks to all for your suggestions.

```
find /path/to/parent/folder -mindepth 1 -type d -exec sh -c 'cd "$0" && rm -rf -- *' {} \;
```

Comment: Ah, so you only care about preserving the timestamp of the topmost directory, right? Not the 600+ in your “handful” of directories...